# Using a function pointer to pthread_create causes segfault

Tags: c, unit-testing, pthreads, function-pointers, stub

I am attempting to stub out pthread_create to be able to fully unit test a module.  When the function pointer is called from within the test framework a segmentation fault occurs. If I debug the program using 'gdb' I am able to directly call the function pointer and it works correctly.

I am using CppUTest as the unit test framework and have compiled my object files using gcc.

This function has worked in production code prior to altering it to use a function pointer for pthread_create, so I am confident in the function in general.

Stack Trace from GDB

```
> Starting program:
> /home/lucid/depot/torr_linux_common_dev/main/src/Utilities/tests/testRunner
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db
> library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
> 
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x080660c4 in
> sys_pthreads_create () (gdb) backtrace
> #0  0x080660c4 in sys_pthreads_create ()
> #1  0x08049ee4 in th_start_thread_name (thread=0x8049e64 <TestThread>, arg=0x0, opts=0x0, name=0x0) at thr.c:177
> #2  0x08049e47 in test_ThreadTestGroup_ThreadCreateUnnamed_wrapper_c () at thr_test.c:66
> #3  0x08049223 in TEST_ThreadTestGroup_ThreadCreateUnnamed_Test::testBody
> (this=0x806cc90) at testRunner.c:21
> #4  0x0805576a in PlatformSpecificSetJmpImplementation ()
> #5  0x08053ab7 in Utest::run() ()
> #6  0x080550d5 in UtestShell::runOneTestInCurrentProcess(TestPlugin*, TestResult&) ()
> #7  0x08053645 in helperDoRunOneTestInCurrentProcess ()
> #8  0x0805576a in PlatformSpecificSetJmpImplementation ()
> #9  0x08053b8f in UtestShell::runOneTest(TestPlugin*, TestResult&) ()
> #10 0x080530ef in TestRegistry::runAllTests(TestResult&) ()
> #11 0x0804a3ef in CommandLineTestRunner::runAllTests() ()
> #12 0x0804a4e9 in CommandLineTestRunner::runAllTestsMain() ()
> #13 0x0804a628 in CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(int, char const**) ()
> #14 0x08049246 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff244) at testRunner.c:25
```

If I call the function pointer from within gdb it works

```
(gdb) p (*sys_pthreads_create)(&thr, 0, thread, arg)
[New Thread 0xb7c01b40 (LWP 17717)]
$4 = 0
```

Function I am testing

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "mypthreads.h"
long th_start_thread_name(TH_THREAD_FUNC thread, void *arg, th_opts *opts, const char* name)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    int ret, sret;
    //pthread_create(opts ? &opts->thr : &thr, NULL, thread, arg);
    ret = (*sys_pthreads_create)(opts ? &opts->thr : &thr, 0, thread, arg);
    if (ret == 0 && name != NULL)
    {
       extern int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thr, const char *name);  /* Fix warning from missing prototype. */

       sret = pthread_setname_np(opts ? opts->thr : thr, name);
       /* pthreads says that thread names must not exceed 16, including NULL. */
       if (sret != 0 && strlen(name) > 15)
       {
           ret = -1;
       }
    }
    return (long)ret;
}
```

mypthreads.h

```
extern int (*sys_pthreads_create(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *,
                             void *(*) (void*), void *));
```

mypthreads.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int my_pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    printf("Did you get the messsage?");
    return pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}


int (*sys_pthreads_create)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) = my_pthread_create;
```

Edit: Added output from gdb when I call the function pointer and it succeeds.

Comment: Observe that according your debugger, you didn't even enter `my_pthread_create`. Maybe you are somehow shadowing your function pointer and have garbage in the copy that you are calling.

Comment: Consider building your code with debug information, and possibly with optimization disabled.  Gdb should then be able to give you more information about the error.  Note also that you can still examine the stack after gdb catches the segfault -- debug information will help with that, too.

Comment: @Jens Gusted" Yes, I am aware the my_pthread_create never got called. If I execute "p (*sys_pthreads_create)(&thr, 0, thread, arg)" from within gdb the function pointer is called correctly and gdb shows that the thread is spawned.

Comment: Enable debug symbols in your build. So you can see exactly which memory access is causing the problem

Comment: @kaylum I have debug symbols enabled, but can't make much sense of it beyond that.

Comment: Are you sure you have that enabled on the entire build? It does not seem to be enabled for `mypthreads.o`.

Comment: mypthreads was build with the following: gcc -g -D_REENTRANT -DQTC_TARGET_LINUX -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -o LINUX_INTEL/mypthreads.o  mypthreads.c
Maybe on of the other flags is messing things up.

Comment: the header file is missing the multiple include guard statements.  the `extern` modifier is not needed.  the `TH_THREAD_FUNC`  is not defined anywhere in the posted code.  the `th_opts` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.  the `sys_pthreads_create` redeclared as different kind of symbol. the `_REENTRANT` is not utilized in the posted code.  the `QTC_TARGET_LINUX` is not utilized in the posted code

Comment: when debugging with `gdb`, the `-g` parameter should be: `-ggdb`

Comment: @user3629249 All good insight. The symbols that are undefined or not used are part of the backend build structure and I'm not interested in ripping it apart
Can you expand on the 'sys_pthread_create' comment

Comment: the prototype for `sys_pthread_create()` and the actual call do not have matching signatures.

Comment: how do you expect us to debug your problem if key definitions, data structures, etc are not included in the posted code?

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the insight with '-ggdb'. That is one I was unfamiliar with. I am just ramping up on using gdb again after quite a few years away from Linux development.

Comment: what was expected to be done with this line: `int (*sys_pthreads_create)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) = my_pthread_create;
`?

Comment: `-ggdb` and `-g` mean the same thing on Linux - it's the default debugging info type on that platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your declaration in `mypthreads.h` has the wrong type:

```
extern int (*sys_pthreads_create(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *, void *(*) (void*), void *));
```

Due to a misplaced parantheses, the type of this symbol is a function that returns a pointer to `int`, but your actual `sys_pthreads_create` object is a pointer to a function.

This means that when you call:

```
ret = (*sys_pthreads_create)(opts ? &opts->thr : &thr, 0, thread, arg);
```

`sys_pthreads_create` is converted to a pointer to a function by implicitly taking the address of it, then that address is dereferenced and called.  But that's not really the address of a function - it's the address of a pointer to a function! So the call jumps into the data segment where `sys_pthreads_create` lives and crashes when it tries to execute the function pointer as code (or crashes due to a non-executable mapping).

There's a clue to this in the gdb output:

```
#0  0x080660c4 in sys_pthreads_create ()
```

It says that it's executing within `sys_pthreads_create` - but `sys_pthreads_create` is a variable, not a function.

The compiler would have diagnosed this for you if you had included `<mypthreads.h>` in `mypthreads.c`, because the conflicting types for `sys_pthreads_create` would have been visible to it (that's why you should always include the header file that declares objects in the source files that define those objects).

The correct declaration of course is the one that matches `mypthreads.c`:

```
extern int (*sys_pthreads_create)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The reason that `gdb` was able to call the function pointer successfully was that gdb uses the type information stored in the debugging info to determine the type of `sys_pthreads_create`, not the bogus information from the header file.